# How do you say "blah blah blah" in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice, translation

As usual, I was mentally translating everyday, common things the other day for practice and wanted to say *blah blah blah*, but I wasn't sure if there was an already established way of saying this in Esperanto. Is there?

Comment: *jada, jada …* :P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- *Bla bla* — blah blah
- *Um um um* — mumble mumble
- *Babil babil* — natter natter
- *Klaĉ klaĉ* — gossip gossip

http://vortaro.net/#blabla

I think most European languages use the *blabla* formula.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of bla, bla is in ancient Greek. The Greek explorers encountered people at the northern shores of the Black Sea and in their ears the local parlance sounded like bar, bar, from which came the word barbarian and the manner how they speak.

Addendum 2019-09-27:
Therefore I think *bla, bla* is quite widely understood.

Comment: While this is interesting and relevant information - as currently phrased, it doesn't answer the question. Are you proposing that "bla bla" can be used in Esperanto for the same purpose as in other languages, too? If so, please [edit] your question to say so explicitly.